# is numpy representation a column vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I want to multiply the matrix w with vector v. (I just discovered that we don't have support for math in SO... annoying)

[image]

```
w = np.array([np.array([1,3]), np.array([2,4])])
v = np.array([np.array([5]), np.array([6])])
print(w)
print(v)
print(np.dot(w,v))

[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
[[5]
 [6]]
[[23]
 [34]]
```

This code seems completely unituitive. A vector is a representation of multiple components. So I expect the vector to be an array e.g. `np.array([5,6])`
This makes a lot of sense because we have a unit of a vector with 2 components.

It becomes even bizarre with the matrix. `[1,2]` are the components for the first basis vector, but we have to write it across 2 different vectors? I expected the syntax to be `np.array([np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])])`. If we write it this way, it makes all components of the first basis vector to sit nicely in an array.

Am I missing something here or numpy syntax is completely bonkers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code seems completely unituitive. A vector is a representation of multiple components.

Strictly speaking, the code in the question isn't a multiplying a matrix times a vector. It's multiplying a matrix times a matrix, which is why the result is 2D.

> So I expect the vector to be an array e.g. `np.array([5,6])` This makes a lot of sense because we have a unit of a vector with 2 components.

You can do that. If you `dot` a 2D array with a 1D array, NumPy will interpret it as a matrix times a vector. Example:

```
w = np.array([np.array([1,3]), np.array([2,4])])
v = np.array([5, 6])

print(w)
print(v)
print(np.dot(w,v))
# [[1 3]
#  [2 4]]
# [5 6]
# [23 34]
```

> It becomes even bizarre with the matrix. `[1,2]` are the components for the first basis vector, but we have to write it across 2 different vectors? I expected the syntax to be `np.array([np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])])`. If we write it this way, it makes all components of the first basis vector to sit nicely in an array.

If you prefer to represent a matrix as being composed as a series of column vectors rather than row vectors, you can do that.

Example 1:

```
w = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).T
```

This creates an array, then transposes it.

Example 2:

```
w = np.column_stack([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

This directly creates the array via column vectors.

Either approach seems like it would work.

Comment: > Either approach seems like it would work.
This has been a cause of confusion for me. What does this actually mean in linear algebra `np.array([np.array([1,3]), np.array([2,4])])`. Is this a matrix with 1,2 in the first column and 3,4 in the second column? Or is it 1,3 in the first column and 2,4 in the second column?

Comment: @smellerbee The former.